# android - Why this code does not make a notification in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-broadcast, android-notification-bar

I want to make a notification from BroadcastReceiver. I'm using this code in my activity and it works fine but I can't make a notification from  BroadcastReceiver . Could you help me to solve this problem :

```
Random rd;rd= new Random ();
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            notificationIntent.setData(Uri.parse(link));
            PendingIntent pending=null;
            pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, notificationIntent, pending.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            Notification myNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setAutoCancel(false).setLargeIcon(remote_picture)
                    .setContentTitle(onvan).setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                    .setContentText(msg).setContentIntent(pending).build();
            notificationManager.notify(rd.nextInt(75), myNotification);
```

The problem is , this code does not make a notification and no notification is showing in the tray .as I say , I run this code in Activity and it works find but in   BroadcastReceiver it does not make any notifications

Comment: Please explain what "I can't make a notification from BroadcastReceiver" means.

Comment: Problem unclear; notification is made fine and the notification manager is notified of it. There should be a Notification in the notification tray waiting for you. Because you always use the same ID, every notification will overwrite the same one in the notification tray.

Comment: @Shark thanks for reply , I just update my code and put a random number for notification ID but it doesn't shows any notification in tray .

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for reply , I need to make a notification in the tray but this code is not making any notifications

Comment: You can't do it in the `BroadcastReceiver` because that one only provides the `onReceive()` method. You need to post the notification in the `onHandleIntent()`method, which is usually done from a `GCMIntentService extends IntentService` class.

Answer (score -1):

To execute the code inside BroadcastReceiver you have to call sendBroadcast() method or set some action in your Manifest file like

```
<receiver android:name="Your package name.ReceiverName">  
<intent-filter>  
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    //set your action here  
</intent-filter>  
</receiver>
```

Comment: You do need the `<intent-filter>` in AndroidManifest but that's also not a proper way to do it.

You need `<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>` to receive GCM push notifications.

Comment: @Shark. In the question donald draper doesn't mention anything about GCM push notification. It seems like he is just trying to send notification from broadcast receiver.

Comment: True, sorry about that, it was my wrong presumption. But I cannot remove the downvote until the answer is edited.